# Showing results for a quiz app (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a quiz app that is working properly, but the thing is the user must answer all questions correctly in order to win the game(if the player gets it wrong the game will be over) .

What I wanted to do is have the questions answered and then at the end there will be an activity that will show how many the player has answered then there will be the options to retry and go back to menu

**This is the code for the maingameactivity**

```
public class MainGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FButton buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD;
TextView questionText, triviaQuizText, timeText, resultText, coinText;
TriviaQuizHelper triviaQuizHelper;
TriviaQuestion currentQuestion;
List<TriviaQuestion> list;
int qid = 0;
int timeValue = 20;
int coinValue = 0;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
Typeface tb, sb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);

    //Initializing variables
    questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuestion);
    buttonA = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    buttonB = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    buttonC = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    buttonD = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
    triviaQuizText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuizText);
    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
    coinText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coinText);

    //Setting typefaces for textview and buttons - this will give stylish fonts on textview and button etc
    tb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TitilliumWeb-Bold.ttf");
    sb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/shablagooital.ttf");
    triviaQuizText.setTypeface(sb);
    questionText.setTypeface(tb);
    buttonA.setTypeface(tb);
    buttonB.setTypeface(tb);
    buttonC.setTypeface(tb);
    buttonD.setTypeface(tb);
    timeText.setTypeface(tb);
    resultText.setTypeface(sb);
    coinText.setTypeface(tb);

    //Our database helper class
    triviaQuizHelper = new TriviaQuizHelper(this);
    //Make db writable
    triviaQuizHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //It will check if the ques,options are already added in table or not
    //If they are not added then the getAllOfTheQuestions() will return a list of size zero
    if (triviaQuizHelper.getAllOfTheQuestions().size() == 0) {
        //If not added then add the ques,options in table
        triviaQuizHelper.allQuestion();
    }

    //This will return us a list of data type TriviaQuestion
    list = triviaQuizHelper.getAllOfTheQuestions();

    //Now we gonna shuffle the elements of the list so that we will get questions randomly
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    //currentQuestion will hold the que, 4 option and ans for particular id
    currentQuestion = list.get(qid);

    //countDownTimer
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(22000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //here you can have your logic to set text to timeText
            timeText.setText(String.valueOf(timeValue) + "\"");

            //With each iteration decrement the time by 1 sec
            timeValue -= 1;

            //This means the user is out of time so onFinished will called after this iteration
            if (timeValue == -1) {

                //Since user is out of time setText as time up
                resultText.setText(getString(R.string.timeup));

                //Since user is out of time he won't be able to click any buttons
                //therefore we will disable all four options buttons using this method
                disableButton();
            }
        }

        //Now user is out of time
        public void onFinish() {
            //We will navigate him to the time up activity using below method
            timeUp();
        }
    }.start();

    //This method will set the que and four options
    updateQueAndOptions();


}


public void updateQueAndOptions() {

    //This method will setText for que and options
    questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
    buttonA.setText(currentQuestion.getOptA());
    buttonB.setText(currentQuestion.getOptB());
    buttonC.setText(currentQuestion.getOptC());
    buttonD.setText(currentQuestion.getOptD());


    timeValue = 20;

    //Now since the user has ans correct just reset timer back for another que- by cancel and start
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    countDownTimer.start();

    //set the value of coin text
    coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));
    //Now since user has ans correct increment the coinvalue
    coinValue++;

}

//Onclick listener for first button
public void buttonA(View view) {
    //compare the option with the ans if yes then make button color green
    if (currentQuestion.getOptA().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
        buttonA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
        //Check if user has not exceeds the que limit
        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {

            //Now disable all the option button since user ans is correct so
            //user won't be able to press another option button after pressing one button
            disableButton();

            //Show the dialog that ans is correct
            correctDialog();
        }
        //If user has exceeds the que limit just navigate him to GameWon activity
        else {

            gameWon();

        }
    }
    //User ans is wrong then just navigate him to the PlayAgain activity
    else {

        gameLostPlayAgain();

    }
}

//Onclick listener for sec button
public void buttonB(View view) {
    if (currentQuestion.getOptB().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
        buttonB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {
            disableButton();
            correctDialog();
        } else {
            gameWon();
        }
    } else {
        gameLostPlayAgain();
    }
}

//Onclick listener for third button
public void buttonC(View view) {
    if (currentQuestion.getOptC().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
        buttonC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {
            disableButton();
            correctDialog();
        } else {
            gameWon();
        }
    } else {

        gameLostPlayAgain();
    }
}

//Onclick listener for fourth button
public void buttonD(View view) {
    if (currentQuestion.getOptD().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
        buttonD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.lightGreen));
        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {
            disableButton();
            correctDialog();
        } else {
            gameWon();
        }
    } else {
        gameLostPlayAgain();
    }
}

//This method will navigate from current activity to GameWon
public void gameWon() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameWon.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

//This method is called when user ans is wrong
//this method will navigate user to the activity PlayAgain
public void gameLostPlayAgain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayAgain.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

//This method is called when time is up
//this method will navigate user to the activity Time_Up
public void timeUp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Time_Up.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

//If user press home button and come in the game from memory then this
//method will continue the timer from the previous time it left
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    countDownTimer.start();
}

//When activity is destroyed then this will cancel the timer
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    countDownTimer.cancel();
}

//This will pause the time
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    countDownTimer.cancel();
}

//On BackPressed
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

//This dialog is show to the user after he ans correct
public void correctDialog() {
    final Dialog dialogCorrect = new Dialog(MainGameActivity.this);
    dialogCorrect.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    if (dialogCorrect.getWindow() != null) {
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        dialogCorrect.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    }
    dialogCorrect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_correct);
    dialogCorrect.setCancelable(false);
    dialogCorrect.show();

    //Since the dialog is show to user just pause the timer in background
    onPause();


    TextView correctText = (TextView) dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.correctText);
    FButton buttonNext = (FButton) dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.dialogNext);

    //Setting type faces
    correctText.setTypeface(sb);
    buttonNext.setTypeface(sb);

    //OnCLick listener to go next que
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //This will dismiss the dialog
            dialogCorrect.dismiss();
            //it will increment the question number
            qid++;
            //get the que and 4 option and store in the currentQuestion
            currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
            //Now this method will set the new que and 4 options
            updateQueAndOptions();
            //reset the color of buttons back to white
            resetColor();
            //Enable button - remember we had disable them when user ans was correct in there particular button methods
            enableButton();
        }
    });
}


//This method will make button color white again since our one button color was turned green
public void resetColor() {
    buttonA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
    buttonB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
    buttonC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
    buttonD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
}

//This method will disable all the option button
public void disableButton() {
    buttonA.setEnabled(false);
    buttonB.setEnabled(false);
    buttonC.setEnabled(false);
    buttonD.setEnabled(false);
}

//This method will all enable the option buttons
public void enableButton() {
    buttonA.setEnabled(true);
    buttonB.setEnabled(true);
    buttonC.setEnabled(true);
    buttonD.setEnabled(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thats good but whats the issue?

Comment: The app doesn't have a results screen (I know that I will add an activity and all that) and what the app does is that the game ends if the user has picked the wrong answer. What I wanted it to do is have the results screen (regardless if every answer is wrong,instead of being game over with 1 wrong answer I want it to display how many questions the user answered correctly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

Just remove the wrapper `if else` inside all the buttons better to keep it as, don't repeat the code. I am assuming the screen that shows result is handled inside `gameWon` and you have implemented functionality for `inCorrectDialog`

```
public void buttonA(View view) {
 Button button = (Button) view;
 buttonPressed(button);
}
public void buttonB(View view) {
 Button button = (Button) view;
 buttonPressed(button);
}

public void buttonC(View view) {
 Button button = (Button) view;
 buttonPressed(button);
}

public void buttonD(View view) {
 Button button = (Button) view;
 buttonPressed(button);
}

public void buttonPressed(Button button) {

 button.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.lightGreen));
 if (qid < list.size() - 1) {
  disableButton();
  if (currentQuestion.getOptA().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
   correctDialog();
  } else {
   inCorrectDialog();
  }

 } else {
  gameWon();
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! the code works but:

1. "button.setButtonColor" doesn't work for some reason (but it's fine)
2. the dialog boxes is sometimes hit or miss (sometimes the question shows correct if answered the wrong and incorrect if correct and there are also times where the correct and incorrect are working properly)
3. It doesn't show the dialog box for the final question

4. This will be an upcoming problem for me but when gameWon runs how do I code it like "YOU GOT _/10"

Comment: Just try removing - 1 from if statement